# Does C-3PO ever link Luke to Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, c-3po, anakin-skywalker

As we see in *The Phantom Menace*, it was Anakin Skywalker who first built C-3PO during his youth on Tatooine. Years later in *A New Hope*, Threepio (with Artoo) finds himself back on Tatooine and end up in the hands of Owen Lars and ultimately, Luke. Does C-3PO ever make the connection and realise that Luke is Anakin's son?

Comment: At the end of Episode III.  Bail Organa ordered:  "Have the protocol droid's memory wiped".  So no, not likely.

Comment: @JaneS - I was going to answer the question with this same fact. You should make the comment an answer

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell I wasn't sure if it was complete enough to provide an answer, but I have done so now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the end of *Revenge of the Sith*, Bail Organa ordered that C-3PO's memory be wiped.

From the [Star Wars fandom page for "Memory Wipe"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_wipe):

> "I'm placing these droids in your care. Treat them well. Clean them up. Have the protocol droid's mind wiped." - Bail Organa, to Wedge Antilles

So given that, it's highly unlikely that C-3PO would have any chance of recognising Luke or linking him to Anakin.

Comment: additionally, the only time we hear the name "Skywalker" in the film is when Luke says his full name to Leia in the detention cell iirc.

Comment: Can you remind me why R2-D2 doesn't tell him?

Comment: @ThruGog There is no canon answer for that as far as I'm aware.  Maybe R2-D2 understood the reasoning for keeping Leia and Luke hidden away and knew that C-3PO was likely to blurt it out if he was aware it.  Given C-3PO's comments about how he was looking forward to telling the children stories of the Jedi and their father, that was a distinct possibility.

Comment: Not only is R2 brave, clever and resourceful, he's also socially shrewd lol